# iOS Equivalent for Android TabLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, viewpagerindicator

I am developing an app which involves paging(Horizontal Scroll). Which i achieved through `UIPageViewController`.

Whereas i need help and suggestions to achieve the design i have attached below in the image -> The pager in the bottom with the Title, Filled circle and the Line. The pager scrolls along with the page and the respective circle is filled/selected.

In android they use a customised version of `TabLayout`. I want to figure out the equivalent in iOS

[image: Screen Sample Design]

Comment: Idk....Maybe [Read the docs for UIControls](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPageControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPageControl-SW1)? And you're gonna need to customize it yourself. Bear in mind however, when developing for iOS, you should strive to maintain iOS touch and feel to the app

Comment: Yes, i think i UIPageControl is the only option. But not sure how it can be customised

Comment: See this library may help https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: Hello future comment reader, in 2008 until 2017 apple had this sample project called "PageControl: Using a Paginated UIScrollView" which comes very close to what the OP needed: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITabBarController

Comment: No tabBar wouldn't equate to the design shown in the shared pics. He is gonna need a Page control for that

Comment: Yes i know that but IOS has its own design Concept so why we need to make it like Android

Comment: Beats me. Suggested as much to the OP. Doesn't matter though, this doesn't even get close to the OP's requirement. His best bet is PageControl, not TabControl.

Comment: yes if she need to achieve that, she can go with PageControl or can google for some library

Comment: makes sense @AhmedSahib i think `UIPageControl` is the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIPageViewController` and also `UIPageControl`, for the circle animation coupled with the changing of the pages or View Controllers.

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) is a tutorial on how to implement it.

Comment: He is already using UIPageViewController, he wants to customize it.

Comment: Thats what i said, to use PageControl, as its what he wants.